# Question about the use of the Min-Max method in solving evolution equations.

Tags: reference-request, elliptic-equations

in elleptic PDE's i used Min-Max methods and critical points researche to find my weak equations and i learnd about their techenics however, i didn't find up to this time references speaking of this metter, and i'm hoping to find any one here who can sugest me some BOOKs or pushes me to the right way.
Thanks for all.

Comment: A basic reference for this subject is the book "Semilinear Elliptic Equations for Beginners: Existence Results Via the Variational Approach", Serra and Badiale or the textbook Nonlinear Analysis and Semilinear Elliptic Problems from Ambrosetti and Malchiodi.

Comment: Thank you but i allready read these two books, and there is no trace of how to use the cited methods in equations other than the elliptic ones there.